# Rails Search Not Working On Mobile with Heroku

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, heroku, devise

I am running into an interesting situation. I am currently running an app that is very basic, and I have a searching function that searches for users (devise gem). It works great locally, and great on Heroku. It's a mobile first web application, so I've also been testing it on mobile with Nitrous.io. I mention this because the search function is working on mobile devices, tested on iOS Safari and Chrome only so far, using Nitrous.io's cloud server.

All of that being said, it seems that when I am running the app on a mobile device, *and* on Heroku, it merely isn't displaying the results of my search. I feel like I am just missing something really dumb.

Here is my user model:

```
def self.search(search)
 search.blank? ? [] : all(:conditions => ['email LIKE ?', "%#{search.strip}%"])
end
```

Here is my view:

```
<% if (@user) %>
 <% if (@user.empty?) %>
  <p>Search for your connections by email address!</p>
 <% else %>
  <% @user.each do |user| %>  
   <% if current_user.email == "#{user.email}" %>
     <!-- display nothing -->
   <% end %>
   <div class="search-card">
    <%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar), user %></p>
    <%= link_to "#{user.firstName}", user %>
    <%= link_to "#{user.lastName}", user %>
    <%= link_to "#{user.company}", user %>
    <%= link_to "#{user.email}", user %>
     <% if current_user.friends.exists?(user) %>
      <%= link_to "View this connection", user, :class => "btn btn-add" %>
     <% else %>
      <%= link_to "View this person", user, :class => "btn btn-add" %>
      <%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :class => "btn btn-add", :method => :post %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also in my view, here is the search form:

```
<%= form_tag(users_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", class: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Users", class: "search-form" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. And yes it was really really simple.

The reason it was only broken on mobile and Heroku at the same time was because my mobile searches defaulted the first letter as an uppercase letter, while my desktop browser searches were only conducted in lowercase.

Essentially, Postgres doesn't accept uppercase searches. To solve this, I just added some ruby to my users model to automatically downcase the searches.

Changed my users model to this:

```
def self.search(search)
  search.blank? ? [] : all(:conditions => ['email LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase}%"])
end
```